# web scraping in Python by taking input

Tags: python

I am using code that will get a link from the user and then find some particular thing in the html codes of the page. But whenever I am giving the link to the program , it directly opens the browser and opens the link instead of executing the next codes.when I give the link in the code primarily , it runs perfectly...what to do ?

Comment: can you clarify and show some code?

Comment: please show what code you're using

Comment: #<li class="_2-riNZ">Intel Core i5 Processor (8th Gen)</li>
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
a=input("Give The Link: ")
request=requests.get("http://{}".format(str(a)))
#request=requests.get("http://flipkart.com")
contents=request.content
soup=BeautifulSoup(contents,"html.parser")
element = soup.find("li",{"class": "_2-riNZ"})
print(element.text.strip())    @CoreyGoldberg ,Is this correct ?

Comment: add code to your question, not unformatted in comments